# Junit Test For reading from a JsonNode

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have a code where I am reading a json from a text file using JsonNode

```
//inside class
@Mock ObjectMapper objectMapper;

//inside method
byte[] byte = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(abc.txt));
JsonNode jsonNode= objectMapper.readValue(byte,JsonNode.class);
JsonNode node = jsonNode.path("id");
```

below is the json structure in the file as:

```
{ "id" : 
      {
         "firstName": "something",
         "lastName" : "something"
      }
}
```

I want unit Test code for this block as

**I am very new to Junit testing**

Answer (score 1):

To construct JsonNode you can use

```
String jsonString = "{ \"id\" : \n" +
                "      {\n" +
                "         \"firstName\": \"something\",\n" +
                "         \"lastName\" : \"something\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "}";

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        
        JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(jsonString);
```

and after that you can easily mock behaviour of mapper using

```
when(objectMapper.readValue(any(), any())).thenReturn(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Mockito to mock Object Mapper's behaviour, Something like

```
when(objectMapper.readValue(any(), any())).thenReturn(your expected value);
```

So basically, you mock the behaviours of the dependent classes and verifies the test class's behaviour.

This should help - https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html

Comment: I tried mocking objectMapper with when but how to return  JsonNode Object. How to construct JsonNode Object ?

Comment: JsonNode is a abstract class, You have to mock it's behaviour as well.

Comment: when I debug this , as the test comes this line "JsonNode jsonNode= objectMapper.readValue(byte,JsonNode.class)";  the jsonNode shows null.